# Positioning two child divs one centered and other top-right/bottom-right inside another div

Tags: css, positioning

I have two `div`s inside a container `div` & I am trying to position one of the child divs at the center (vertical & horizontal) and another at top-left/bottom-right of the container.

Both the child `div`s contain only text. I tried a few things and was able to get both these styles applied individually, i.e. if only one of the two `div`s was there it would work as required. I am unable to figure out how do I get both styles to apply simultaneously. I tried playing around with positions and z-index, but due to my limited `CSS` knowledge I have not been able to get a breakthrough.

**Update**: I want the text to be centered w.r.t to the outer container.

### HTML

```
Top left works
<div class="container">
    <div class="topLeft">value</div>
</div>
Center Works
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">label</div>
</div>
Both don't work simulaneously
<div class="container">
    <div class="topLeft">value</div>
    <div class="center">label</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    border-width:1px;
    width:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    display:table;
    height:300px;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:5;
}
.topLeft {
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    z-index:10;
}
```

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/E5zGw/

I am mainly targeting IE8+ and chrome and have flexibility to change both html and css if needed

Comment: Absolute positioning?

Comment: You need to position 2 inner elements, one top left, the other one center-middle ?

Comment: yes @MilchePatern both positions are w.r.t to the outer contianer & not the text's position w.r.t the inner div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `.container` div `position: relative;` and then `position: absolute;` to the children divs to position them simultaneously, using `left` and `top` properties:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E5zGw/14

You just need to  get rid of the `display: table-cell` as its not needed if you this route.

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd div in you jsFiddle doesn't have the label as horizontally centered

Comment: yes almost there with the /10 fiddle. Just that the label's top left is aligned with the center of the div. I would like the label's center to align with the container's center. If I don't get anything else I may go ahead with this. Thanks!!

Comment: Haha thanks for trying so hard, unfortunately the length of the string may vary a little bit, so a longer text would look out of place a little. I think I can do something with jQuery to figure out the exact left/right offsets.

Answer (score 0):

your cells are behaving like `<TD>` out of a `<TR>`.

Just encapsulate your DIVS inside something like a TableRow

http://jsfiddle.net/E5zGw/6/

[jsFiddle with background-colors](http://jsfiddle.net/E5zGw/9/)

CSS added :

```
.table-row {
    display:table-row;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML added :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="topLeft">value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="center">label</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Witch is exactly like :

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="left">value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">label</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**NOW**, let me try to fit it like you think you want it to fit :

[jsfiddle.net/E5zGw/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/E5zGw/15/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="topLeft">value</div>
    <div class="center">label</div>
</div>

.topLeft {
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is vertically middled ;)

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd div in you jsFiddle doesn't have the label as vertically centered

Comment: Jugal, it is centered and middled .. it's the DIV witch takes 50% of total height .. this is why it looks like on bottom.... Add a border to DIVs, you'll see.

Comment: Yes, I want the text to be centered w.r.t to the outer container. Sorry if the question wasn't clear, I'll update it

Comment: My question was always what it was. Sorry if it wasn't as clear to you as it may have been to others.